# Prepare human models for 3D printing (non-manifold mesh)

Tags: 3d-printing

I'm relatively new to Blender. My ultimate aim is to make some 3d printed human models/figures for a 1:43 scale model diorama.
I've used Makehuman to create a model, removed the head, and added a head modeled in Facebuilder.

[image: screenshot]

How do I attach the head to the overalls/firesuit, for example?
I've tried 'option select' in edit mode using *LoopTools* to try and bridge between the 2, but failed.

I've tried 'option J' on the collar of the firesuit to try and change the tri's to quad's, but again failed.

I've tried using the *3D Print Toolbox* add-on to clean up and make manifold, but the suit just disappears.

Can I ask for some direction? I'd be very grateful for some help.
I'm on a Mac running Blender 4.0.2

[image]

Thank you for your replies.

I think the problem with the model is that I created it in Makehuman and then imported it in to blender. I then made loop cuts around the wrists (as the main body was none existent), to separate the head from the hands, replaced the head with my head model made in facebuilder.

I've now installed MPFB2 in blender so I'll have another attempt by making the model with this addon within blender.

What should the main workflow be?
I've found this following video helpful with some of the workflow;
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBgdtlUIrY4

Comment: Hi. Please use a title that matches the content of the question. It should be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the issue so that anyone searching for a similar problem is likely to find it. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "*this*", "*help with*", "*issue*" or "*question about*", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on how insightful it is. See [*What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"*](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2449)

Comment: Hi. I'm not familiar with 3d printing but the mesh of the model must be manifold and solid (thickness). The suit has no thickness and has holes (sleeves, neck, button placket of the shirt, trouser legs). The *Solidify* modifier can add thickness but does not work very well on the triangulated mesh and it won't close the holes. The *Remesh* modifier is probably the better choice. But you should fix the belt first. You can separate it and apply the *Solidify* modifier to give it thickness and join it with the original mesh again. However, the belt has a few strange issues. (->2)

Comment: 2) Remove the *Subdivision Surface* modifier from the suit. It won't help you with the randomly triangulated mesh. It looks like there is something wrong with the mesh of the suit since you cannot separate the belt. If you try (select with key L, then key P > Selection) it gets duplicated(?) and the faces are missing(?!). Weird. Also, the SubD modifier goes completely crazy. Anyways, you can separate the belt, remove all inner vertices between the outer edge loops, and recreate the faces (create an edge, then use the key F to fill the loop). Delete belt vertices from the original mesh.

Comment: 3) Apply a *Solidify* modifier, and join it with the original mesh. The order of selection matters because only the active object (orange selection) will keep its modifiers. The other selected objects (red) will lose their modifiers. Then fix the neck (sculpt brush), and apply a *Remesh* modifier. Try *Smooth* with 9 levels. Be careful, the higher the level the more vertices you get (Blender can freeze if there are too many). Finally, you should have a high-poly manifold mesh. Don't forget to make a backup copy beforehand, as the application of modifiers is destructive and cannot be undone!